# Translate Instruction Pointer Address (in shared library) to Source Instruction

Tags: c, linux, pointers, ip, instructions

**Are there any tools or libraries one can use on Linux to get the original (source) instruction only from the PID and the current instruction pointer address, even if the IP currently points into a shared library?**

AFAIK it should be possible, since the location of the library mapping is available through `/proc/[PID]/maps`, though I haven't found any applications or examples doing so.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: an assembly instruction or the nearest symbol suffice (source code line is not necessarily needed)

Comment: Besides being off-topic (see ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for details) no it's not possible. Not unless you already have the source locally.

Comment: I think GDB can do this which use the debug flag to compile the application and library.

Comment: An assembly instruction would be enough, I don't necessarily need the source line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this with GDB:

Interactive:

    `$ gdb --pid 1566
    (gdb) info symbol 0x7fe28b8a2b79
    pselect + 89 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    (gdb) info symbol 0x5612550f14a4
    copy_word_list + 20 in section .text of /usr/bin/bash
    (gdb) info symbol 0x7fe28b878947
    execve + 7 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Shows exactly what I wanted!

It can also be scripted:

`gdb -q --pid PID --batch -ex 'info symbol HEX_SYMBOL_ADDR'`